# Chome Dev Tools - ConsolePlugin

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I don't know what happened in my Google Chrome Console, I can't see any longer the source of my console.log.

If I write a console.log in my code, I can see the result in the console but not the source of my code, now instead of the source I see "consolePlugin", and when I click on it, it redirects me to a file called `consolePlugin.ts`.
It's very annoying, because I would like to debug sometimes from inside the console of Chrome, or know where this console.log comes.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: I suspect this is not DevTools issue. Try to check the import statement in your sourcecode if it imports "console" from somewhere which "hijack" the call. 

Another way is to click open the consolePlugin.ts file in the Sources panel, then right click "Add to ignore list".

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found a solution by now but having just fixed this here was my solution;

In the Chrome Console I clicked on the "consolePlugin.ts" which took me to the Sources tab and showed me that the output was coming from a file in webpack.

[consolePlugin in the Sources tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVd9g.png)

I then went to Chrome settings (the gear icon) and then to Ignore List where I added the file "consolePlugin.ts".

My console logs are now back to normal. Hope this helps

[Ignore List addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DLip.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening but most of the time when I experience a strange behaviour from devtools I reset settings and it solves the problem.

Click here :

[image]

And then :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work properly. I still have this consolePlugin instead of the source of my console.log.